# Sticky social share after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its me again and I have another jQuery question.

Here is my social share buttons code:

```
<div class="articleLeft">
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>
</div>
```

How can I make this div sticky after user has scrolled `300px` ?

[image: The image http://prntscr.com/30b6uq]

Which method should I use?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a try with this:

JS:

```
function stick_social() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (window_top > 300) {
        $('.articleLeft').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('.articleLeft').removeClass('stick');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(stick_social);
    stick_social();
});
```

CSS:

```
.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 300px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```